# Python multiprocessing: weird performance?

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, performance-testing

I have experienced some weird performance issues with python multiprocessing in a project of mine. At first I thought it has something to do with the scenarios in my project, but it happened so often that I began to be suspicious. <strike>For example 2 or 3 processes in parallel often had the best performance (although I am running the code on 4 and 8 core machines)</strike>. Additionally running 2 or 3 processes created nearly 100% load on 2 / 3 cores but when I ran 4 or more processes the load always was wavering between <strike>60</strike> 70 to 90% on the 4 core machine and like <strike>30</strike> 50 to 90% on the 8 core one.

For testing purposes and a having a clean scenario I wrote a very simple reduce worker and tested the performance. Although the load was more balanced than in my reasonably bigger project, it showed up with comparable performance flaws.

My test script always returns values like this:

```
1 core : 25.49051s
2 cores: 15.41679s
3 cores: 11.03758s
4 cores:  8.94643s
5 cores:  9.31251s
6 cores:  9.41158s
7 cores:  9.06828s
8 cores:  8.99581s
```

**Does anyone have an idea why this happens?** Of course, due to overhead, I did not expect to have some nearly linear saving in execution time...but at least I expected all cores to go for 100% load and I absolutely expected that the execution time will decrease not increase with more cores.
( the 4 core machine is an Intel i5 quad core and the 8 core one an AMD FX 8 core )

**Here is the testing code**:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import timeit
import time


def sum_worker(q, xs):
    q.put(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, xs))


def sum_it_up(xs, num_threads = 4):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    worker = []

    part_low = 0
    part_high = len(xs)/num_threads

    for i in range(0, num_threads):
        worker.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=sum_worker, args=(queue, xs[part_low:part_high] )))
        worker[i].start()
        part_low += len(xs)/num_threads
        part_high += len(xs)/num_threads

    for i in range(0, num_threads):
        worker[i].join()

    result_list = []

    while not queue.empty():
        result_list.append(queue.get())

    sum_worker(queue, result_list)

    return queue.get()
```

Debug printing, running timeit and printing the times:

```
lst = list(np.random.randint(1, 100, 10000000))

print("Starting reduce - single core")
time_single = timeit.timeit("reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lst)", "from __main__ import lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 2 cores")
time_parallel_2cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 2)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 3 cores")
time_parallel_3cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 3)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 4 cores")
time_parallel_4cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 4)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 5 cores")
time_parallel_5cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 5)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 6 cores")
time_parallel_6cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 6)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 7 cores")
time_parallel_7cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 7)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("Starting reduce - 8 cores")
time_parallel_8cores = timeit.timeit("sum_it_up(lst, 8)", "from __main__ import sum_it_up, lst", number=10)
print("done!\n")

time.sleep(1)

print("\nResults:\n")

print("1 core : {0:8.5f}s").format(time_single)
print("2 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_2cores)
print("3 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_3cores)
print("4 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_4cores)
print("5 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_5cores)
print("6 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_6cores)
print("7 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_7cores)
print("8 cores: {0:8.5f}s").format(time_parallel_8cores)
```

Comment: look at your subscripting of xs to pass to the process

Comment: oh my god! thanks, will fix it and test again...

Comment: maybe rename threads to processes, it adds a bit to confusion since you are not spawning threads.

Comment: ok, the partition is fixed and now it gets better. Thanks @Sneftel...but the weird behavior having nearly 100% load (like 95-100% on 2 and 3 cores with 2 and 3 processes) stays nearly the same. Now the load is a bit more balanced than before but overall it is still wavering between 50 and 90% when having 4 or more processes...

Comment: spawning processes is not free, they each have a copy of your list too... so if it happens to be very big that will take longer and longer the more processes you spawn, so that may explain why the efficiency falls off quicker if you spawn more and more processes

Comment: so the drops and wavering loads are normal due to the additional costs for scheduling 4 or more processes?